# Force webcam to use MJPG as default only

Tags: linux, webcam

i have image issue with 1224:2a25 Jieli camera. Camera is working in browser but not in VLC or OpenAuto. I figured out, that YUYV 1280x720 is not working resolution...but this is unfortunately used as default by VLC or OpenAuto. I can run video with `vlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=mjpg:width=1920:height=1080`, but in OpenAuto is hardcoded default YUYV path. Is there solution for forcing use of MJPG as default? Or disable offering of all YUYV streams?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x320
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
```